NameError after updating to Rails 7
My app got blasted to the present recently from 2017 (Rails 5.1 to 7.1.3.4).
Previously I could randomly update objects in console like:
object.update(variable: true)

But I'm getting this error when attempting on this one class:
 irb(main):008> asdf.update(expired:true)
(irb):8:in `<main>': Missing model class BananaShacks for the ExpirationDate#banana_shacks association. You can specify a different model class with the :class_name option. (NameError)

              old_raise.call(*args)
                       ^^^^^
/home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:264:in `compute_type': uninitialized constant ExpirationDate::BananaShacks (NameError)

              old_raise.call(*args)
                       ^^^^^
    from /home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:468:in `compute_class'
    from /home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:412:in `klass'
    from /home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:571:in `check_validity!'
    from /home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:42:in `initialize'
    from /home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/associations.rb:320:in `new'
    from /home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/associations.rb:320:in `association'
    from /home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:104:in `banana_shacks'
    from /home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activemodel-7.1.3.4/lib/active_model/validator.rb:152:in `block in validate'
    from /home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activemodel-7.1.3.4/lib/active_model/validator.rb:151:in `each'
    from /home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activemodel-7.1.3.4/lib/active_model/validator.rb:151:in `validate'
    from /home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:426:in `block in make_lambda'
    from /home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:202:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
    from /home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:707:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
    from /home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:706:in `catch'
    from /home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:706:in `block in default_terminator'
    from /home/dave/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:203:in `block in halting'
    ... 62 levels...

BananaShack:
has_many :expiration_dates

ExpirationDate
belongs_to :banana_shacks

The only thing I'm noticing is that it says BananaShacks in the error, when it should be BananaShack, or at least that's what the class name is (banana_shacks / BananaShack).
Not seeing any answers on Google except maybe redoing the database

should be singular belongs_to :banana_shack

was staring me right in the face. guess rails 5.1 didn't care about that?

also, optional:true, should be a way to set that as default for validations instead of vice versa, like back in good ol '17. ... still, things are literally 4 times faster. guess i didn't get the memo on updating

Directly from 5.1 to 7.1? Upgrade should be step-by-step

belongs_to associations must use the singular term. If you used the pluralized form in the above example for the banana_shack association in the ExpirationDate model and tried to create the instance by ExpirationDate.create(banana_shacks: @banana_shack), you would be told that there was an "uninitialized constant ExpirationDate::BananaShacks". This is because Rails automatically infers the class name from the association name. If the association name is wrongly pluralized, then the inferred class will be wrongly pluralized too.
After some research it seems this pluralization became very strict after v6.1.0, that could be the reason why it used to work before the upgrade.
